# SimpleCaptcha: how to make upper-case letters always larger than lower-case letters?

Tags: java, captcha, simplecaptcha

I use Java-based SimpleCaptcha for my web application. I notice that the the case of letters generated by SimpleCaptcha are hard to recognize in some cases. See the following two examples:

[image]

In the above, it is difficult to know "c" is in lower-case or upper-case because it has the same height as upper-case "N" has. This is another example:

[image]

In this example, it is difficult to know "o" is upper-case or lower-case.

I hope to be able to make  upper-case letters always show larger than lower-case letters. OR make the upper-case letters always have the same height, and lower-case letters always have the same height too. Maybe another way is: make SimpleCaptcha not change the size of letters or digits.

Comment: you could silently ignore case when you check the user input?

Comment: luksch, thanks for your input! I am able to ignore the case in the backend. Is case-insensitivity a best practice in Captcha practice?

Comment: I don't know about that, but I would say that weakening an already weak captcha is not that big of a deal when comparing with frustrated users.

Comment: A user still have to try HARD to figure out whether a letter is in upper-case or lower-case even though case is insensitive in the backend. Right? Are you aware of any better Java Captcha solutions? Thanks!!!

Comment: I would agree. Just don't mention it :) You can use https://github.com/google/recaptcha-java if you are a Google fanboy

Comment: Thanks for the google recaptcha info. I used it before, but later took it out because I need to have captcha embedded in the application.

Comment: All the captchas I'm ever presented with seem to be case-insensitive. It would be unpleasantly surprising to find out the hard way that yours wasn't.

Comment: This might help: see  "Each character is written individually."    on this page : https://processing.org/tutorials/text/. This is exactly what is needed to answer the question and need: it is an example of how graphically draw each letter in a different size.